# SQL - GROUP BY Month Period Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table(contracts)the rows have a created date col that I would like to GROUP by month, but the end-user wants the month to run from the 26th to 25th.

So 11 (November) would be 2020.10.26 - 2020.11.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract 25 days from the date and extract the month.  I would do this using `apply`.  Here is an example:

```
select datefromparts(year(v.mon), month(v.mon), 1) as month, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (dateadd(day, -25, datecol))) v(mon)
group by datefromparts(year(v.mon), month(v.mon), 1)
```

Note:  This makes the month October rather than November.  If you want it to be November, just add a month:

```
from t cross apply
     (values (dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, -25, datecol)))) v(mon)
```